# Trouble-shooting Time Manager date format problem

Tags: date, format, timemanager

I've been trying to format a field in a vector file in QGIS to be run in Time manager and, for some reason I can't figure out, it still is not running. I read the other threads here associated with this problem, and so I reformatted the date to conform to what Time Manager says is an acceptable format - YY-MM-DD. My cells currently look like: 07-01-01 for Jan 1, 2007. I created it as a string variable and then tried converting it to a date variable in field calculator. I still keep getting the same error message which is:

An error occured while trying to add layer scicafe_07-16-pointshapefile to TimeManager. Cause: Exception(UnsupportedFormatException('Could not match value PyQt4.QtCore.QDate(2015, 1, 1) with any of the supported formats. Tried: 
...lists lots of other formats..and  %Y-%m-%d.

But as far as I understand, the format 07-01-01 is %Y-%m-%d, so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong? I also tried YYYY-MM-DD too by the way. Same error message.

How can I troubleshoot this problem?

Comment: `QDate(2015,1,1)` part in the error message seems to be showing your field type is Date and it has a Date without Time. If you create a new text field by `to_string("your_date")`, Time Manager can read it, perhaps?